# Pandas create list of columns with row values containing ' & " delimeter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset tracking professional golf statistics with over 1500 columns. Many of the features are stored in feet and inches (ex. 6' 2"), where python treats it as a string. With so many columns I can't list the name of each column that contains a feet and inch measurement. I would like to find all the columns that contain both a ' & ". I then will be able to use the code I have to convert the feet and inches measurement to just inches. Here is an example of some of the code I have tried.

```
df1 = df.ix[:,df.gt('"').any()]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `str.contains` with a regex on the starting DataFrame, then `.any()` the resulting boolean values.

```
cols = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('\'|"')).any().index
df1 = df[cols].copy()
```

This probably isn't the fastest (or most elegant) solution, but I hope your table is small enough that it doesn't matter!